# MySQL Foreign Key Constraints issue when importing from MySQL workbench file

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Rio VAMOOS Database`.`Card` (
  `Card_id` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `Card_start_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `Card_end_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `State_validity` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `Official_Official_id` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Card_id`),
  INDEX `fk_Card_State1_idx` (`State_validity` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Card_Official1_idx` (`Official_Official_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Card_State1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`State_validity`)
    REFERENCES `Rio VAMOOS Database`.`State` (`Card_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Card_Official1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Official_Official_id`)
    REFERENCES `Rio VAMOOS Database`.`Official` (`Official_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: We can't seem to work out why we are getting the error code when importing, we have checked through multiple times but cannot find the problem. any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Check if the foreign keys are ok, `State_validity` need to be of the has the same type as `Card_id` in table `State`. Same for `Official_Official_id` and `Official_id`

Answer (score 0):

There are also should be tables `Rio VAMOOS Database`.`State` and `Rio VAMOOS Database`.`Official`. Without these tables you will get `ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint` while trying to run this query.

You should check that these two tables importing before `Rio VAMOOS Database`.`Card`